# Specifying a CSS class for a view

Tags: 7, views, theming

In Drupal 7 using Views 7.x-3.3, I've specified a CSS class for the view under Advanced -> Other -> CSS class.  I have my CSS class defined in my custom theme CSS file as...

TABLE.listView {
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

but the view is not using the class.  When I look in FireBug I see it using a class "views-table cols-5".  If I overwrite that class in FireBug with the one I created in the theme, the view table is styled the way I want it to look.  How can I get views to use the CSS class I've specified?  All I'm trying to do is get the table styled the way I want it to look.

Comment: if you look via FireBug "up a couple divs" does your class show up?  meaning, Views adds that class in the very very beginning of its output, and you might just not be cascading it down enough...

Comment: Yes it is up a couple divs:  <div class="view view-document-library view-id-document_library view-display-id-page listView view-dom-id-3fa26a2967f6fa39b7e3ca1da3f8df22"> then <div class="view-content"> then <table class="views-table cols-5">.  The class for the table tag "views-table cols-5" is where I can put in my class listView and have the table rendered correctly.  So it looks like the CSS class for the view sets the class for everything that makes up the view:  title, filters, table, etc.  Any ideas on CSS that would work knowing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the commentary above, all you should need to do is cascade your class/table, eg, something along the lines of...

```
.listView table {
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My lack of basic CSS knowledge gets me again.  I didn't have the class defined correctly.  Thanks for your help!